# Java PaintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Another PaintComponet question because I just don't seem to find and answer I'm looking for. So lets just get right to my goal. I have a game that will require multiple states/screens. for instance I'm stuck trying to switch from my MainMenuState to my GameSetupState(user can add computer players/more players) which are subclass of my state class.

```
public abstract class State{

    private static State currentState = null;

    protected Game game;

    public static void setState(State state) {
        currentState = state;
    }

    public static State getState(){
        return currentState;
    }
    public State(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    public abstract void update();

    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
}
```

this is my Jpanel class that I'm want to draw to.

```
public class MyCanvas extends JPanel {

    private Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private int width =(int) d.getWidth()/6;
    private int height =(int) d.getHeight()/3;
    protected Game game;
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
       drawHeight(g);
       drawWidth(g);
    }

    public void drawHeight(Graphics g){
        for(int i=1;i!=3;i++){
           g.drawLine(0, height*i, (int)d.getWidth(),height*i);
       }
    }

    public void drawWidth(Graphics g){
        for(int i=1;i!=6;i++){
           g.drawLine(width*i,0, width*i,(int)d.getHeight());
       }
}
```

So from the extensive reading of the PaintCommponet its not good practice to call that method from  out of MyCanvas class, so my big question is how would i get PaintComponet invoked when my state changes?

snipp of my game loop

```
private void update() {
    if (gameState != null) {
        State.getState().update();
    }
}

private void render() {
    if (gameState != null) {
        //g.clearRect(0, 0, dimension.width, dimension.height);
        State.getState().render(g);
    }
}

 while (running) {
     update();
     render();
 }
```

Comment: how would i get PaintComponet invoked - Call the repaint method for the JPanel.

Comment: If you swap views with CardLayout, the painting methods are automatically called and painting is thus refreshed. If you manually swap views, then it is up to you to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that holds the view.

Comment: Your animation loop looks to be uncontrolled and perhaps unrealistic

Comment: Thanks you 2 I feel super silly that i didnt find such a simple answer....